# How to save a Spinner and it's adapter using OnsavedInstance and restore it after?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner, onsaveinstancestate

I have a problem with handling `onSavedInstance` and `onRestoreInstance` for my two spinners in app.

I have two `SpinnerAdapter` that can be dynamically fill with pair  of `ArrayAdapter<String>`- adapter1/adapter2 and adapter3/adapter4.

In onCreate method app create 4 adapters for them, when user press `button1` it fill `spinnerFrom` and `spinnerTo` with adapter1 and adapter2,when `button2` fill spinners with adapter3 and adapter 4 respectively.

As i understant lifecycle - when screen rotates, android destroys app and then restore it from the beginning .

So in `onSavedInstance`i put my spinner into bundle

```
savedInstanceState.putInt("from",spinnerFrom.getSelectedItemPosition);
savedInstanceState.putInt("to",spinnertTo.getSelectedItemPosition());
```

on restore i retrieve them from bundle:

```
spinnerFrom.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("from"));
spinnertTo.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("to"));
```

The problem is: when app restore it lose my adapters and they get null value.

To check it i created technical button and next code:

```
 protected void checkAdapter () {
       //get Adapter from spinners
        SpinnerAdapter valueAdapter = spinnerFrom.getAdapter();
        SpinnerAdapter resultAdapter = spinnertTo.getAdapter();

    if (valueAdapter == null | resultAdapter== null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, “adapter null” , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
    Toast.makeText(this, “adapters not null” , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }
```

Question: How properly put AdroidSpinner and it's adapter into OnSavedInstance bundle and then restore it onRestoreInstance in case when it populates not in onCreate but in onClick methods?
Thanks in advance!

App java code:

```
      import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.SpinnerAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import butterknife.BindView;
    import butterknife.ButterKnife;
    import butterknife.OnClick;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
        protected double getEnteredValue;
        protected SpinnerAdapter checkAdapter;
        protected int pos;
   protected ArrayAdapter<String> adapter 1, adapter2, adapter3,
                adapter4;

//butterknife bindings
@BindView(R.id.unit_From_spinner)Spinner spinnerFrom;
@BindView(R.id.unit_To_spinner)Spinner spinnertTo;
@BindView(R.id.radio_result_group) RadioGroup resultGroup;
@BindView(R.id.radio_value_gropu) RadioGroup valueGroup;
@BindView(R.id.valueEditTextView) EditText valueEdit;
@BindView(R.id.resultView) TextView resultView;
@BindView(R.id.conver_button) Button  convertButton;

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         savedInstanceState.putString("result",resultView.getText().toString());          savedInstanceState.putString("value",valueEdit.getText().toString());         savedInstanceState.putInt("from",spinnerFrom.getSelectedItemPosition);
savedInstanceState.putInt("to",spinnertTo.getSelectedItemPosition());
savedInstanceState.putInt("radGroup1",resultGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
savedInstanceState.putInt("radGroup2", valueGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        }


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.unifiedlayout);
            ButterKnife.bind(this);

//adapters for spinners 
adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,getResources().getStringArray( R.array.adapter_1) );
adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,getResources().getStringArray(R.array. adapter_2));
adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,getResources().getStringArray( R.array. adapter_3) );
adapter4 = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,getResources().getStringArray(R.array. adapter_4));}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            resultView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("result"));
            valueEdit.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("value"));
            spinnerFrom.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("from"));
            spinnertTo.setSelection(savedInstanceState.getInt("to"));


            super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        }

//OnClick
@OnClick({R.id.button1, R.id.button2,R.id.button3,R.id.button4} )
public void setViewOnClickEvent(View view){
    switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id. button1:
        fillSpinner(adapter1, adapter2); // fill spinner with values
                break;
            case R.id. button2:
                fillSpinner(adapter3,
                        adapter4);
                break;
        //button for check if any adapter active
         case R.id.buttonAdapter:
        checkAdapter () ;   
               break;   
       }
    }

//fill spinners when user checks radiobutton in radiogroups
protected void fillSpinner (final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerToAdapter,
                                final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerFromAdapter){

        valueGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup valueGroup, int checkedId) {
                pos = valueGroup.indexOfChild(findViewById(checkedId));
                switch (pos) {
                    case 0:
                        spinnerFrom.setAdapter(spinnerToAdapter);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        spinnerFrom.setAdapter(spinnerFromAdapter);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        resultGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup resultGroup, int checkedId) {
                pos = resultGroup.indexOfChild(findViewById(checkedId));
                switch (pos) {
                    case 0:
                        spinnertTo.setAdapter(spinnerToAdapter);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        spinnertTo.setAdapter(spinnerFromAdapter);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

//simple method for check if both spinners has null value
protected void checkAdapter () {
   //get Adapter from spinners
    SpinnerAdapter valueAdapter = spinnerFrom.getAdapter();
    SpinnerAdapter resultAdapter = spinnertTo.getAdapter();

if (valueAdapter == null | resultAdapter== null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, “adapter null” , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else{
Toast.makeText(this, “adapters not null” , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
```

EDIT: Answer isn't perfect it don't works how i want yet, but this way give me possibility to save adapter:
1.Create method to retrieve string array from adapter that want' to be saved :

```
public static String[] getStringArray(SpinnerAdapter adapter) {
        String[] a = new String[adapter.getCount()];

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            a[i] = adapter.getItem(i).toString();

        return a;
}
```

2.In onSavedInstanceState put next code:

```
// here i saving arraylist that ussualy i get from resources.
 savedInstanceState.putStringArray(ADAPTER_TO,getStringArray(spinnerFrom.getAdapter()));
            savedInstanceState.putStringArray(ADAPTER_FROM,getStringArray(spinnerFrom.getAdapter()));
```

3.In restoreInstance create new adapter that will fill yours spinner with values and use savedInstanceState.getStringArray(ADAPTER_TO) to populate with saved values :

```
toAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, savedInstanceState.getStringArray(ADAPTER_TO));
fromAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, savedInstanceState.getStringArray(ADAPTER_FROM));
     //use spinner.setAdapter to set created adapter.
    spinnerFrom.setAdapter (fromAdapter)
    spinnerTo.setAdapter (toAdapter)
```

This still not work properly as i want, but if you want to save spinner state on rotation screen you can try use this logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using two methods. 1) (recommended) Using ViewModels (architecture components) 2) using save and restore state.

1). You can create a viewModel and whenever the user selects something, call  the ViewModel with the specified value. By observing the ViewModel, you can get the latest changes to that value (even after rotation changes) because ViewModel will stay alive.

3) Hold user's selection in a local variable inside your activity, then in save and restore, `put` and `get` your value like following:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  savedInstanceState.putInt("firstSpinnerPosition", variableThatHasTheChangedPosition);
  savedInstanceState.putInt("secondSpinnerPosition", variableThatHasTheChangedPositionForSecond);
  // other stuff.
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  variableThatHasTheChangedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("firstSpinnerPosition");
  variableThatHasTheChangedPositionForSecond = savedInstanceState.getInt("secondSpinnerPosition");
//notify your adapter of the changes

}
```

Comment: I can't understand last one, isn't it equal to that i wrote in my code?   
As i wrote - adapters populates when user click button and after screen rotates any active adapter in spinner are become null.  
So i must save adapters in  onSaveInstanceState and call spinner.setAdapter when app calls onRestoreInstanceState?

Comment: Are you sure you have your items (and your adapter is ready to use) when onRestoreInstanceState is called? If not, you have to put the info that you get from onRestoreInstanceState in some variable, and then after you initiate and populate your adapters, set their values accordingly.

Comment: Are you sure you have your items (and your adapter is ready to use) when onRestoreInstanceState is called? - No, when app Restore itself - it doesn't see any adapters because they creates not onCreate memthod, so even with saved getSelectedItemPosition it do nothing. So i must save active adapter like Adapter adapter = spinnerfrom.getAdapter()? and then set saved adapter in onRestoreInstanceState ?

Comment: You need to save your items somehow (not the adapter itself) - using bundle or anything that can hold the items and create the adapter with the items. If you cannot do that, you can save the selected position in a variable, and use it when your data is ready.

Comment: oh, okay i get it.
First i get arraylist from adapter (r.array.name), than I save it using ,custom method and savedInstanceState.putStringArray . Then i put it in onrestoreinstaince  like Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, savedInstanceState.getStringArray(listrFromSavedinstande) and then just put in my spinner using setAdapter,

Comment: Exactly. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Spnner has `onNothingSelected()` method.
In that method, try playing with `spinneradapter.getLastVisiblePosition()`.
When you off the app, save last position and when you come back, use that last position.
Hope it helps.